# Vuetify conditional dark theme

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify to create my social media website. The problem that I'm facing now is that I want to use dark attribute, so user can switch between normal and dark theme. The thing is that I can't use any of Vue's conditional rendering methods, as dark is not an attribute that you can bind. Below is the part of code that you use to apply dark theme:

```
<v-app dark>
```

Comment: Can you bind `:dark="true|false"` ? 
Check the demo at https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/dedMRE?

Comment: You, my friend, are my savior. It worked! I don't even know how I didn't manage to find that anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes `dark` or `light` are not attributes, they are `props` which can take values, in this case `true` or `false`

You can find this in vuetify's documentations.

[image: dark theme]
[image: light theme]

Props are the properties which are used for communication with child components. And are prefixed with `:` in order to distinguish it with normal properties.

Coming to the solution.

```
<v-app :dark="true">
```

or

```
<v-app :dark="false">
```

You can replace true or false with any reactive data options or computed properties to make the theme change programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to persist theme with [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Inside `plugins/vuetify.js` or `plugins/vuetify.ts` add this:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    //
    dark: localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark',
    //
  }
})
```

then on the button you want to switch theme apply the following function:

```
switchTheme() {
  this.$vuetify.theme.dark = !this.$vuetify.theme.dark;

  localStorage.setItem('theme', this.$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'dark' : 'light');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme) says you can just update variable `this.$vuetify.theme.dark`:

> You can manually turn dark on and off by changing this.$vuetify.theme.dark to true or false.

Comment: This is correct for vuetify 2.x. The question was asked for a vuetify 1.x. environment. Toggle dark/light theme in each version is completely different

Answer (score 1):

**If a component is used as the App:**

```
<template>
   <v-app :dark="isDark"></v-app>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      data () {
         return {
            isDark: false,
         }
      },
   }
</script>
```

**It can also be called from the app instance**

thru its instantiated object defined property
`app.__vue__.isDark = isDark`
when being instantiated like :

```
const app = new Vue(
    {
        data: () => ({
            isDark: false
        }),
    }
)
```

So it can be called from other component